# Real Numbers Hausdorff in Lower Limit Topology?

Tags: general-topology

So I'm brushing up on point-set topology...

Clearly, $\Bbb{R}$ is Hausdorff in the lower limit topology. My proof was basically this:

Let $x,y\in \Bbb{R}:x<y$ (WLOG). Then $\forall x,y\in\Bbb{R}\exists [\,x,y)\,,[\,y,y+1)\,\in\Bbb{B}\Rightarrow x\in[\,x,y)\,\land y\in[\,y,y+1)\,\land[\,x,y)\,\cap [\,y,y+1)\,=\emptyset$, hence the space is Hausdorff.

What I'm curious about is, in addition to the above argument, some people say to define $a=\frac{y+x}{2}$ and use the sets $[\,x,a)\,,[\,a,y+1)\,$, but aren't we working too hard? Can't one, by Completeness, decree that $\forall x,y\in\Bbb{R}:x<y\exists a,b,c,d\in\Bbb{R}:a\leq x<b\leq c\leq y<d$, hence $\Bbb{R}$ is Hausdorff in the lower limit topology? It seems to me that the Hausdorff condition in this topology is almost tautological given the definition of $\Bbb{R}$.

Am I being crassly informal? Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Pardon my typo, edited.

Comment: Your argument is fine. The only other reasonable approach that occurs to me is to prove that every Euclidean open set in $\Bbb R$ is open in the lower limit topology, so that Hausdorffness of the lower limit topology follows from Hausdorffness of the Euclidean topology. And this is working too hard *unless* you want to know that the lower limit topology is finer than the Euclidean topology, a fact that actually is fairly useful.

Comment: I'm a year late, but thank you, professor!